# How to remove everything after first instance of specific delimiter, then before last instance of specific delimiter using Regex? - SQL

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I want to format the strings in a table column, in a specific format.

Input Table:

```
file_paths
my-file-path/wefw/wefw/wef/wfweof=wefonwe/wfewoi=weoif/
my-file-path/wefw/wef/ef=wefonwe/wfewoi=weoif/
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wefw/wef/ef=wefonwe/wfewoi=weoif/
```

I want to remove everything after the first `=` sign, then remove everything before the `=` sign and after the last `/` sign.

Output:

```
file_paths
my-file-path/wefw/wefw/wef/
my-file-path/wefw/wef/
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wefw/wef/
```

I'm thinking of doing something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(file_paths, 'regex_here', '', 1, 'i')
FROM my_table
```

I'm unsure of how to write the RegEx for this though. I'm also open to easier methods of string manipulation, if there are any. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(file_paths, '[^/=]+=.*', '', 1, 'i')
FROM my_table;
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZq1Hh/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex:

```
^(.*?\/)(?=[^\/]+=).*$
```

and replace it by group 1

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0BynkH/1)

Comment: Most likely the forward slashes do not require any escaping.

Comment: May be didn't usually think much about this so usually try to be fail proof :P. But does that hamper  execution time ?